# Local variables whose definitions depend on each other

Tags: function-construction, variable-definitions, functional-style

Consider the following (pseudo-)function definition:

```
f[l_] := Let[{
          a = Length[l],
          b = First[l],
          c = b/a,
         }, c*10]
```

So for instance, `f[{2,3,4,5}]` should output `5`.

Currently, I only know variants for `Let` that

- set `a`, `b` and `c` globally (on the first call of `f`) or
- don't allow the definition of `c` because `a` and `b` are not defined.

What is the most simple way to define *local* variables whose definitions may depend on each other (upwards)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have **Version 10** use the function `Where` in the `GeneralUtilities` package like this:

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]

f[l_] := Where[a = Length[l], b = First[l], c = b/a, c*10]
```

Then:

```
f[{2, 3, 4, 5}]
```

> 5

Comment: I think it would be better to post this answer to the related main post so that it can be easily found (see link in question)

Answer (score 4):

Why not just this?

```
f[l_] := Block[{a,b,c},
          a = Length[l];
          b = First[l];
          c = b/a;
          c*10]
```

Then

```
f[{2, 3, 4, 5}]
```

> ```
> 5
> ```

Comment: Ah, so that's how you use `Block`. Thanks!